# "Insmod normal" command returns "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: boot, grubrescue, boot-repair, boot-partition

I've got the issue shown below:

```
error: attempt to reader write outside of disk 'hd0'
Entering rescue mode...
```

It happened in the past, so I tried

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: attempt to reader write outside of disk 'hd0'
```

Well, after enter `"insmod normal"` command, the next command would be `"normal"` and next would be `"boot"`, but doesn't work fine at this time. I don't understanding what's happened because I've got the same problem in the past and I've used the same procedure and works fine.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thank for you contribuition @heynnema. As soon as possible I'll tried fixed as you recommended

Comment: Unfortunately it dosen't work. The 'grub rescue' does not have many options and the commands you showed above are not possible to execute. Many thanks for you support

Comment: @RonaldoOliveira You must have misread my instructions, because they have nothing to do with GRUB Rescue. Retry the first part of my answer, and if that doesn't work, then use the second method in my answer :-)

Comment: neither option is available - is there no way to correct this from within grub rescue?

Comment: @reukiodo Are you able to get to the GRUB menu?

Comment: no, the system boots directly to grub rescue

Comment: @reukiodo Use the second method from my answer. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB... etc.

Answer (score 1):

change set root to
`$ set root=(hd0,msdos1)/`
and then run

`$ insmod normal`

and

`$ normal`

Comment: `set root=(hd0,msdos1)/` results in `ls /` returning `error: disk '(hd1,msdos1)/' not found.` and `insmod normal` still returns  `error: attempt to read or write outside of partition.`